# What does Disk Queue Length mean under Storage view under Disk tab in Resource Monitor?

Tags: windows, resource-monitor

All but above column name is what I don't understand. What does it measure and how is its value calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk Queue Length contains the average length of disk queue requests.

This metric displays the number of outstanding requests (read and write)
at any given time, meaning requests that are waiting for the disk controller to
execute.

For a classical disk, a high number may indicate that there are not enough
disk spindles/heads to service the needs of the running applications,
or that the disk is too slow to keep up with requests.

For an SSD that can process several requests in parallel, this may mean that requests
are generated faster than the controller is able to service, or that the
disk interface (bus) is too slow.